# declare variable to multiple state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Probably a very basic question, but I can't figure it out. I have a form that uses the following variables as state which returns true/false:

```
ccValid, dateValid, cvvValid, nameValid, addressValid
```

I want to have one variable that is equal to all of these.

Ex.

```
const formValid = {ccValid, dateValid, cvvValid, nameValid, addressValid} = this.state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want a single `Boolean` variable that can be read at anytime to learn the form's current validity state, defined as whether the form's properties `ccValid`, `dateValid`, `cvvValid`, `nameValid`, and `addressValid` are all equal to `true`, you can add a `getter` to the form:

```js
Object.defineProperty(form, 'valid', {
  get: function() { return this.ccValid && this.dateValid && this.cvvValid && this.nameValid && this.addressValid; }
});

console.log(form.valid); // always logs the current form state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all those variables in a single object in the state. For example,

```js
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          validations: {
             ccValid: false,
             dateValid: false,
             cvvValid: false,
             nameValid: false,
             addressValid: false,
        }
      }
    }
}
```

When you need to access each variable, you can destructure the `validations` property from the state, for example

```js
const { validations } = this.state;

// you have access to validations.ccValid, validations.dateValid etc.
```

Let me know if this resolved the issue, or you were looking for something completely different.